# How to identify the values in the array of the historical bars rather than showing "NaN"?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

How to let the historical bars revealing their values in the array rather than showing "NaN"?. However, when I run the replay mode, they're showing a filled array from the first bar of replaying.
The image clarify what I'm referring [Replay mode vs Solid mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKfLs.png)

Comment: Never mind, I just found myself using a `barstate.islast` condition, I erased it and specified `array.new_float(6)` instead of dynamic `array.new_float(0)`. Issue Solved!.

Answer (score 0):

Solution!!!

```
// 1-3) Search for Pivots (High and Low)
PH = pivothigh(close, 5, 4)
PL = pivotlow(close, 5, 4)

// 2-3) Add Pivot Points on array.
var a = array.new_float(6)
if (not na(PH))
    array.unshift(a,PH)
else if (not na(PL))
    array.unshift(a,PL)

// 3-3) Pick-Up the most Last 6 Pivots (High and Low)
var A = array.new_float(6)
A:= array.slice(a, 0, 6)

//=== array ===
y=label.new(bar_index, close, "Pivots\nA= " + tostring(A, '#.##'))
// label.delete(y[1])
```